# Add view at end and start of view pager dynamically

Tags: android, arraylist, android-viewpager

Initially my `ViewPager` takes list and set view accordingly. But if the end of `ViewPager` or start of `ViewPager` is reached I want to add more view to `ViewPager` and set positions accordingly, how can I accomplish this by writing an efficient code?

This is my `Adapter`

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TouchImageView image;

    ImageEntity entity=list.get(position);
    final TextView text;


    inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);

    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    image = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    View progress=itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    text=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    text.setText(entity.message);
    makeTextViewResizable(text, 1, "View more", true);
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Constants.FLDR_IMG+entity.localImageName));
    ContextCommons.loadMainImage(context, entity, progress, image);
    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}`
```

This is custom `ViewPager`

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager{

float mStartDragX;
float x = 0;
OnSwipeOutListener mOnSwipeOutListener;
static final String TAG="CustomViewPager";

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
    mOnSwipeOutListener = listener;
}

private void onSwipeOutAtStart() {
    if (mOnSwipeOutListener!=null) {
        mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
    }
}

private void onSwipeOutAtEnd() {
    if (mOnSwipeOutListener!=null) {
        mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch(ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = ev.getX();
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

    if(getCurrentItem()==0 || getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1){
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch(action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (getCurrentItem()==0 && x>mStartDragX) {
```

/*here i want to update `ArrayList` from start which is supplied to view adapter*/

```
                    ImageActivity.loadStart();
                }
                if (getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1 && x<mStartDragX){
```

//here i want to update Arraylist from bottom which is supplied to view adapter

```
                    ImageActivity.loadEnd();
                }
                break;
        }
    }else{
        mStartDragX=0;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

}

public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
    void onSwipeOutAtStart();
    void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
}
```

}

So I need to update list which is supplied to `ViewPager` to add dynamic view when `ViewPager` reaches the end or start.

I am adding view like this which I think is a wrong approach

```
public static void loadStart(){
    ArrayList<ImageEntity> image = null;
    try {
        ContextCommons.loadImages(context, Constants.DIRECTION_TOP, list.get(0).id);
        image= SelectQueries.getTopLocalImagesOnId(context, list.get(0).id, Constants.DIRECTION_TOP);
        list.addAll(0,image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(image.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: what u want not understand

Comment: In your adapter, in the getView() method, you can check if item at index 0 is requested, you prepend your new pager item to data set and call notifyDataSetChanged(), same goes for end, if data.length position is requested, append data and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @chiragjn I can detect the end and start can you just specify how exactly can i call notifydatasetchange() and set position of viewpager accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some editis to Googles viewPager example to keep it simple,
by clicking the button on fragment you can easily increase the pages to View Pager.

This is a demo I showed here how to notify anychanges as you wish to increase pages. you will have to make your own custom Adapter and list of pages to keep pages and it's position in check...

I am sorry, I would not be witting entire code :(

Make a fragment with following xml and code...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and it's code is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private static AddPage test;


public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test.addAnotherPage();
        }
    });
}

public void setAddPage(AddPage addPage) {
    test = addPage;
}

public interface AddPage {
    void addAnotherPage();
}

}
```

Main Activity xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AddingPagesTest">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activities Code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class AddingPagesTest extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private MyFragment set;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adding_pages_test);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_adding_pages_test, menu);
    return true;
}



private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements MyFragment.AddPage {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.setAddPage(this);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public void addAnotherPage() {
        NUM_PAGES++;
        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I want to send 2 strings to fragment as i will be populating my fragment with 2 text views, how can I do that

Comment: as you would have to make each fragment have it's own Strings it would be better if you make that in your "PagerAdapter" and send this to each fragment you make, Have this Strings in constructor and populate them in your UI in "onActivityCreated" in Fragment